# Whether sencha touch2 supports SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch-2

I am a newbie to Sencha Touch2, and I have started developing some sample applications.I was just wandering that database like SQLite is supported in this? I googled a lot on it but I ended up in searching with Sencha touch2 proxy which is quite like local database.

Any help on this would be appreciated a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends how you've implemented the DB. For example, [CouchDB provides a REST](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128819-ExtJS-4-MVC-Associations-and-CouchDB...-oh-my!) interface, so you can use the REST proxy. Or you can use the [WebSQL interface](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/using-the-sencha-touch-2-1-sql-proxy/) if you want to give that a try. If you only need client-side storage there is also just using the [localstorage proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) (which is pretty dead simple).

I haven't seen an SQLlite implementation, but it's certainly possible. If you have specific questions on implementing a proxy for one of these, maybe update your post with some specific questions or issues you are having.